# MATLAB, frequency table with a class of interval of size 2

Tags: matlab, frequency-distribution

The following data display the number of errors per book for 20 publisher

2, 5, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2

Now i want to compute a frequency table with a class of interval of size 2 and relative frequency by using `MATLAB`.

I can make  a frequency table  by the command `tabulate(x)` but do not finding any reference that  clarify how to compute a frequency table with a `class of interval of size 2`.

Comment: What do you mean by "class of interval of size 2"? That your histogram bins are two integers wide, i.e. classes 0&1, 2&3, 4&5, etc.?

Comment: @A.Donda yes. 0-1, 2-3, 4-5,etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `histc`, which allows to specify the edges of the histogram bins. It doesn't compute relative frequencies or print a table though, you have to do this yourself:

```
% error data
e = [2, 5, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1, 5, 0, 0, 4, 5, 1, 2];

% bin edges
be = 0 :2: ceil(max(e) / 2) * 2;

% absolute frequencies
af = histc(e, be);

% relative frequencies
rf = af / sum(af);

% print table
fprintf('  Value  Count  Percent\n')
fprintf('  %d-%d\t %d\t    %5.2f%%\n', [be; be + 1; af; rf * 100])
```

The result is:

```
  Value  Count  Percent
  0-1    7      35.00%
  2-3    6      30.00%
  4-5    5      25.00%
  6-7    1       5.00%
  8-9    1       5.00%
```